# Where can Symfony services be useful?

Tags: symfony

There is the example of creating and using a service in the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html#services-naming-and-format). At start we create some class, then register it in config/services.yml an then we can use it in our code like this:

```
$result = $this->get('app.myservice')->myMethod($arg);

//(In the [example][1] it is little bit other code:)
//$slug = $this->get('app.slugger')->slugify($post->getTitle());
```

But WHAT FOR? while I can just do the SAME like this:

```
use MyServiceNamespace/MyService
//...
$result = (new MyService())->myMethod($arg);
```

Where is profit of using Services? Is this just syntax sugar?

Answer (score 4):

Nope.  Far from syntax sugar.

You need to have a working understanding of what dependency injection means.  Perhaps start by skimming through here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Let's suppose your service needs a doctrine repository to do it's job.  Which is better?

```
class MyController
{...
    $userManager = $this->get('user.manager');
    OR
    $userRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyBundle::User');
    $userManager = new UserManager($userRepository);
```

Your choice but once you have worked through the mechanics of how to add a service then you will never look back.

I should also point out that your sluglfy example requires a use statement and ties you code directly to a specific implementation.  If you ever need to adjust your slugification then you need to go back and change all the places where it is used.

```
// These lines make your code more difficult to maintain
use Something\Slugify;
$slugify = new Slugify();
AS Opposed to
$slugify = $this->get('slugify');
```

Answer (score 3):

'tIn this case, it's not really relevant. But from a simple design concern, services allow to make a better dependency management.

For instance, if you declare a service relaying on another one, then you won't have to instanciate both of them. Symfony will take care of it.

And since your declaration is centralized, any modification on the way you decide to create your service (= declare it), you won't have to change all the references to the services you changed since symfony will take care of the way it's instanciated when needed.

Another point is the scope of services. This information might be checked, but I think symfony instanciate service once (Singleton) which mean a better memory usage.